# How to show/hide DIV in gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to hide `<div>` when the email address is empty when the data bound to gridview, but it isn't working. Don't know where the mistake it. Please help.

Code behind:

```
protected void gvReportList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            string emailID = drv["email_list"].ToString();
            string tRepID = drv["REPORT_SCHEDULE_ID_C"].ToString();
            string tDvId = "dv" + tRepID;
            if (emailID == "")
            {
               Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>tDvId.style.display = 'none';</script>");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReportList" runat="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title of Report" SortExpression="REPORT_NAME_N">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("REPORT_NAME_N")%>
         </ItemTemplate>   
         <ItemStyle Width="50%"/>    
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns> 
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField  ControlStyle-Width="40%" HeaderStyle-Width="45%" HeaderText="Recipients">
         <ItemTemplate>           
             <div id='dv<%# Eval("REPORT_SCHEDULE_ID_C") %>'> 
                  <table id='tbl<%# Eval("REPORT_SCHEDULE_ID_C") %>'><tr><td><%# Eval("email_list")%></td></tr></table>             
             </div>             
          </ItemTemplate> 
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Your job is to simplify the code and narrow down the problem until you can work out what's wrong. Don't just post the whole damn page. </rant>

Comment: Why not just add `runat="server"` to the div and modify its properties directly from your code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP script in your ItemTemplate...

```
      <ItemTemplate>
         <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("email_list"))) { %>
         <div id='dv<%# Eval("REPORT_SCHEDULE_ID_C") %>'> 
              <table id='tbl<%# Eval("REPORT_SCHEDULE_ID_C") %>'><tr><td><%# Eval("email_list")%></td></tr></table>
          <% } %>
         </div>             
      </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: But I am getting an error , Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: That is super funky because you ARE in the context of a databound control. Maybe you forgot the runat=server or something like that? Check your markup real carefully - I've done the above hundreds of times.